# How to get my local time for a given time in different time zone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I want to get my local time for a given time in a different time zone.
I am getting the time (`6/12/2020 4:23:00 PM`) and the time zone (`America/New_York`) from the API.
How to get my local time using these values.

I found the way to get the time in a different time zone.

```
var aestTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"});
console.log('AEST time: '+ (new Date(aestTime)).toISOString())
```

But I need the other way around.

Comment: So you want your local time when given a time in a different time zone? What format is the given time in?

Comment: @SamuelG Yes indeed, I am getting the time as a string, this is the format `6/12/2020 4:23:00 PM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) (the modern successor of Moment) can do this easily:

```js
const input = '6/12/2020 4:23:00 PM';
const format = 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a';
const zone = 'America/New_York';

const original = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(input, format, { zone });
const local = original.toLocal();

console.log(local.toString()); // an ISO 8601 formatted string
console.log(local.toFormat(format)); // or whatever format you wish
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.24.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Also, be very careful with locale-specific date formats.  I'm assuming you meant `M/d/yyyy` as used in the USA, but in Australia they use `d/M/yyyy`.  It would be all to easy to mix up June 12th with December 6th.  You should prefer `yyyy-MM-dd` formatting when working with APIs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It solved my problem.

Comment: @Brutus - I'm glad I could help!  If this solved the problem, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), on the left-side.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `moment` library.

```
var moment = require('moment')

var date = moment.tz("2020-06-01T12:00:00Z", "Australia/Brisbane")
date.format()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for the answer. But my question is different. I want to get the local time for a given time in a different time zone, not the local time of the given time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward method using vanilla JS.

You could take into account the difference in offset between the runtime, given format, and UTC. Covert the date back to a UTC date and then use `toLocaleString` to display the date in the given format.

Roughly something like:

```js
// create date object - this will be adjusted to utc
const localTime = new Date('6/12/2020 4:00:00 PM');
console.info('local', localTime);

// diff between local runtime and nyc - i am 3 hours behind NYC
const localOffset = -3;

// noew adjust to utc
const offset = localTime.getHours() - localTime.getUTCHours() + localOffset;

localTime.setTime(localTime.getTime() + (localOffset * (60*60*1000)));
console.info('utc', localTime);

// now you can display in locale and timezone
console.info('new york', localTime.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}));

console.info('brisbane', localTime.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```